# ParseUser.signUpInBackground never "done"

Tags: android, parse-platform

I did a pretty standard parse signup following online documentations. Besides that, I tried to achieve automatic login after the user signup by calling logInInBackground in the `done(ParseUser user, ParseException e)` method of the SignUpCallback.

```
user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {

        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // Hooray! Now sign in with the account that has just been created
                ParseUser.logInInBackground(uname, pw, new LogInCallback() {
                    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            Log.d("DONE SIGNUP", "STRANGE");
                            // Hooray! The user is logged in.
                            // Associate this user with this device
                            ParseInstallation curIns = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
                            curIns.put("username", user.getUsername());
                            curIns.saveInBackground();
                            alertMsg.setText("Signed In");
                            //Go to the usermainpage activity
                            Intent mainP = new Intent(ACTLoginSelf.this, ACTRequest.class);
                            startActivity(mainP);



                        } else {
                            // Signup failed. Look at the ParseException to see what happened. =======TBD=========
                            alertMsg.setText("Missing information, cannot proceed! " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                // Sign up didn't succeed. Look at the ParseException
                // to figure out what went wrong
                //report is there are duplicate accounts existing and such! ============TBD============
            }
        }
    });
```

I am not sure why signUpInBackground never seems to be "done", and the new entry was never populated into Parse User Database. Is it because of the automatic sign-in I try to achieve? I made sure that the sign in was initiated by adding `Log.d` at places,

```
12-22 14:39:09.210 1570-1570/com.android.inputmethod.latin I/LatinIME: Starting input. Cursor position = 0,0
12-22 14:39:19.033 26189-26189/com.parse.starter D/SIGNING UP: PLEASE WAIT
```

but it just doesn't seem to finish.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't even bother doing the login. When you signup, the user by default is logged in via the Android client who signed up.

You can access the logged in user as follows:

```
ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
```

No need to login after signup.

EDIT: As a matter of fact, the user persists their login until they clear the cache or the app is uninstalled. (or of course if you programmatically logout as well with Parse SDK)

Comment: Thanks, after I removed the login, it finished quicky. However, it finished with an error: Cannot sign up a user that is already signing up.

Interestingly, I have not signed up this user before. Do you kow why I could be getting this error? I will update my code above. Thanks, @lucas

Comment: Are you hitting the button twice?? or w/e way you start this signup? Link the full stacktrace

Comment: Try uninstalling the app and trying fresh with the changes I proposed

Comment: Another thing, check the Parse dashboard to see if that user already exists... you maybe trying to signup a user that already exists in the previous code that was giving you issues

Comment: I am clicking on the emulator, but I am pretty sure I clicked once. And I tried this many times too. I checked the dashboard and no new user was added at all. Really confused now >_<, everyone else seems to get it working just fine.

Comment: did you try the uninstall and reinstall to see if that fixes it?

Comment: Yes, I uninstalled the app and reinstalled, it didn't work. sigh

Comment: I resolved this issue myself just now. All I did was simply enable anonymous users on the dashboard, and for some strange reason, signing in a regular user works now. I have no idea why, but I did not change my code one bit. Thanks again and sorry for late response. @LucasCrawford